# Failed when followed instruction to setup SSH tunnel for Datalab in Dataproc

Tags: portforwarding, ssh-tunnel, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-datalab

I created a Google Dataproc cluster with Datalab installed. Then I followed the instruction to set up the SSH tunneling. But I got an error. I also tried other ports. Got the same error. Not sure why. I was wondering if anything wrong with command.

Here is my command:

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone us-central1-a hnp-spark-cluster-44de-m -- -4 -N -L port:hnp-spark-cluster-44de-m:8081
```

Here is the error I got:

> Bad local forwarding specification 'port:hnp-spark-cluster-44de-m:8081'
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you probably found a documentation typo; when using local port forwarding you need to specify a local port on the left-hand-side instead of the actual literal word "port", for example, choose 1234:

```
gcloud compute ssh ... -- -4 -N -L 1234:hnp-spark-cluster-44de-m:8081
```

Then you would access on localhost at port 1234.

I can't seem to find which docs you're looking at, since both https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/dataproc-datalab and https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/jupyter-notebook recommend dynamic port forwarding instead; do you have a link to where you're getting the documentation with local port forwarding?

Comment: Dennis Thanks a lot! I was reading the same links that you put here. I was so silly that I read too fast and didn't realize that they meant the word "port" needs to be replaced. I kept thinking the port number at the end.

Comment: Ah I see, you were probably looking at the "console" version of the instructions. Note that if you're doing that local port forwarding in the cloud shell, cloud shell only supports a small range of local ports where it can proxy the web UI; instead of choosing "1234" you'd want to choose one of the ones that can show up in the dropdown like 8080. And the port on the right-hand-side has to be the one where datalab is running, so needs to be 8080 instead of 8081.

Comment: Thanks for the info!